# VSCode terminal font inversed

Tags: visual-studio-code

The font in my terminal windows (powershell and debug) has become inversed. I'm not doing anything with fonts in my code, so I'm unsure how this would have happened.

Is there a way to reset the terminal settings?

Comment: Could you please provide some more information? Do you mean the integrated terminal within VSCode and the external terminal, that opens when you debug? And if invoking Powershell outside of VSCode, are the fonts displayed normal?

Comment: Yes, the integrated terminal within VSCode.
I just tried running powershell independently and it looks fine. (maybe that's what I'll stick with).

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio Code you can to customize the colors of the integrated terminal to suit your needs.

First you'll need to add this line to your `settings.json` (I think this step should already solve your problem):

```json
"terminal.integrated.drawBoldTextInBrightColors": false
```

Then add the following to overwrite the colors you want to modify (if there aren't any displayed at all, you'll probably have to try some):

```json
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "terminal.ansiBlack": "#50ff00",   //this overwrites black colors with green
    "terminal.ansiBlue": "#ff0000",    //this overwrites blue colors with red
    ...
}
```

So, for example if you want to change the black colors into another one (i.e. green), you'll have to asign `"#50ff00"` to `"terminal.ansiBlack"`. As you can see below, there are a few more colors you can change.

Here's how it looks like:

[image]